# How does a redox reaction between ClO- and Br- take place?

Tags: redox

How does a redox reaction between $\ce{NaClO}$ and $\ce{KBr}$ take place?

will bromide be oxidised to bromine?

$\ce{2 Br- + CIO- +  H2O  ->  Cl- + 2 OH- +  Br2}$

or will bromide be oxidised to $\ce{BrO-}$?

$\ce{Br- + CIO-   ->  BrO- + Cl-}$

Answer (score 3):

In the pH range between 10 and 14, chloride and hypobromide are formed ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01174a025)):

$$\ce{OCl- +Br- ->  Cl- + OBr-}$$